# Using a hyper-link in a manual validation task - Azure DevOps (Yaml)

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a url in a manual validation task like below :

```
 - task: ManualValidation@0
      displayName: Export the Power Platform Solution
      timeoutInMinutes: 1440 # task times out in 1 day
      inputs:
        notifyUsers: |
          bob@bob.com
        instructions: |
          'Please follow this link for instructions'
          'https://dev.azure.com/BobsOFfice/ASR/_wiki/wikis/ASR.wiki/1002/Application-Deployment?anchor=export-the-solution'
        onTimeout: 'reject'
```

It looks terrible on the screen and you have hightlight the url and paste it into IE. Is it possible to make this a hyper-link ? I cannot see any docs on this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the manual validation task doesn't support this feature yet.

The instructions field will be displayed in plain text and cannot be displayed as a hyperlink for the time being.

I can fully understand your requirement. Here is a suggestion ticket with the same requirements: [Azure devops Manual Validation Task's instruction is not showing the hyperlink.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-devops-manual-validation-tasks-instruction-i/1552914)

You can vote it and add comment in this suggestion ticket.